# Setting up a class based view architecture with reusable methods and error handling

Tags: python, django

I am struggling how to structure a class based view with reusable methods that should act like validation steps. I don't want to raise actual errors but return json messages (both on success and failure)

```
class View(object):
    ERRORS = (
        ('error_1', 'Enter an integer'),
        ('error_2', 'Enter a valid integer'),
        ('error_3', 'Enter a positive integer'),
    )

    def get_number(request):
        number = request.GET.get('number', None)
            return number
        else:
            return 'error_1', ERRORS.get('error_1')

    def validate_number(number):
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            return 'error_2', ERRORS.get('error_2')
        if number > 0:
            return number
        else:
            return 'error_3', ERRORS.get('error_3')

    def get(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # pseudo code should run reusable method checks
        # then return {'number':number} or {'error_1', 'msg'}

    def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # pseudo code should run reusable method checks
        # then return {'number':number} or {'error_1', 'msg'}
```

The problem is how I should 'break' away from the validation steps. I have tried to return JsonResponse from a validation method but it will continue the get or post method before actually returning any response resulting in errors. I can set a class error and message but that wil mean a lot of if/else checks in the get or post method..

I am basically looking for a class architecture that lets me run validation methods that could have one or two return values.. I think I might have to create my own error handler, but I don't have a clear example.

Comment: Any special reason why you don't use exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take some inspiration from Django's forms framework, and raise some sort of validation exception. Then a separate 'validate' method could call all the validation functions, catch any exceptions, and output the correct JSON result.

Or, you could simply use a Django form directly, which might be simpler all around.